# Newtonsoft.Json.Schema is not validating JSON input correctly against a JSON schema

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

In below example schema validation is returning `true` for the below payload JSON, even though:

- "family_name" and "given_name" are required fields in the "name" property but are missing in the payload JSON.
- "given_name" should be an array of strings but is a simple string in the payload JSON.

Why are these errors not getting caught?

We are using [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) for validation.

JSON Schema :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "article_metadata": {
            "description": "article metadata for descrepancy checks",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "authors": {
                    "description": "authors details",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "list": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "sequence_id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "guid": {
                                    "description": "32 digit unique id to identify author",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "prefix": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "given_name": {
                                            "type": "array",
                                            "minItems": 1,
                                            "items": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "family_name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "required": [
                                            "family_name",
                                            "given_name"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "sequence_id",
                                    "name"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Payload JSON:

```
{
    "article_metadata": {
        "authors": {
            "list": [{
                    "sequence_id": "Au1",
                    "guid": "00208406-c337-4f58-9245-9455d8852a00",
                    "affiliation_id": "Aff1",
                    "name": {
                        "prefix": "Ms.",
                        "family_name": "Hole"
                    }
                }, {
                    "sequence_id": "Au2",
                    "guid": "32b8a598-2fb5-42f1-ad0e-94ce2fc00a8f",
                    "affiliation_id": "Aff2",
                    "name": {
                        "prefix": "Mr.",
                        "given_name": "Anurag"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be reproduced with demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H6GhJJ).

Let's try to break this down into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If we extract a schema for just the `"name"` objects from your overall schema, it looks like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "prefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "given_name": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "family_name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "required": [
            "family_name",
            "given_name"
        ]
    }
}
```

And a corresponding invalid JSON object missing all required properties looks like:

```
{
  "prefix": "Mr."
}
```

If I try to validate the JSON against this schema, the schema itself cannot be parsed, and throws the following error:

> ```
> Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchemaReaderException: Unexpected token encountered when reading value for 'required'. Expected StartObject, Boolean, got StartArray. Path 'properties.required', line 18, position 53.
> ```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ozyA4y).

The problem here is that you have added the list of required properties *as a property itself*.  You need to extract the required properties from the list of properties like so:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "prefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "given_name": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "family_name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "family_name",
        "given_name"
    ]
}
```

Now your schema will load successfully and correctly validate the `"name"` object, generating the following errors:

> ```
> Required properties are missing from object: family_name, given_name. Path '', line 1, position 2.
> ```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xow7lN).

However, your original JSON schema doesn't throw `JSchemaReaderException` error, it simply fails to validate correctly.  Why is that?  It seems that the syntax you are using for the `"list"` array items is wrong -- wrong enough that the Json.NET Schema parser becomes confused.   You do this by immediately listing the property values you expect to find inside the array items, like so:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "sequence_id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "guid": {
            "description": "32 digit unique id to identify author",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
           // Contents omitted for brevity
        },
        "required": [
            "sequence_id",
            "name"
        ]
    }
}
```

However, as shown in https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html, the array items need to be defined in the same way a property value or root object is defined, specifically by indicating the `"type"` of the item (here `"object"`), and then giving the type-specific constraints.  Thus this portion of your schema should look like:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "sequence_id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "guid": {
                "description": "32 digit unique id to identify author",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
                 // Contents omitted for brevity
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "sequence_id",
            "name"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I make this correction to your schema, your JSON now validates correctly, generating the following errors:

> ```
> Required properties are missing from object: given_name. Path 'article_metadata.authors.list[0].name', line 8, position 29.
> Invalid type. Expected Array but got String. Path 'article_metadata.authors.list[1].name.given_name', line 18, position 46.
> Required properties are missing from object: family_name. Path 'article_metadata.authors.list[1].name', line 16, position 29.
> ```

Your final schema should look like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "article_metadata": {
            "description": "article metadata for descrepancy checks",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "authors": {
                    "description": "authors details",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "list": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "sequence_id": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "guid": {
                                        "description": "32 digit unique id to identify author",
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "prefix": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "given_name": {
                                                "type": "array",
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "minItems": 1
                                            },
                                            "family_name": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": [
                                            "family_name",
                                            "given_name"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "sequence_id",
                                    "name"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V0sUwa).